# Как передать данные при асинхронной работе request в Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, асинхронность

Использую модуль `request` следующим образом:

```
var request = require("request");
var url = "http://www.google.com";
//...
request(url, function(error, response, body) {
  var step1 = body.replace(/<.+?>/g, '');
  //...
  console.log(step3);
```

Данные собираются, но я не могу сопоставить исходный запрос с ответом. Подумал, что нужно включить содержание переменной `url` в данные, находящиеся внутри анонимной функции. Но как это сделать, не понимаю.

Что можно сделать, чтобы вывести пары вида `url -> response`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам стоит request обернуть в промис:

```
const _request = url =>{
  return (new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(url,(err,res,body)=>resolve(body));
  }))
}
```

Тут можно про промисы почитать https://learn.javascript.ru/promise

А потом воспользоваться async/await:

```
var urls = [
  'http://www.google.com/0',
  'http://www.google.com/1',
]
(async ()=>{
  let list = [];
  for(let url of urls){
    let body = await _request(url);
    list.push([url,body])
  }
  console.log(list);
  return list;
})();
```

Вот тут про async/await https://javascript.info/async-await

Цикл for можно заменить на следующий код:

```
let list = await Promise.all(urls.map(async url=>{
  let body = await _request(url);
  return [url,body];
}));
```

Тогда запросы отправятся в один момент, асинхронно и Promise.all будет ожидать исполнения всех запросов

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ознакомлюсь с промисами. Слышал, но пока не пользовался.